# Can I make Android Notification Text Icons colorful?

Tags: android, notifications, png, assets

Is it possible to make Notification Text Icons colorful? There is no provision to assign color in the Android Studio's Image Asset Studio.

Is there any outside source where I can generate colorful notification text icon png's?

Thanks!
An Android noob.

[image: Android Studio - Image Asset Studio]

Comment: Notification icons are supposed to be this way, just using the alpha channel, as the background color behind them varies by app.

Comment: And if you make an icon, make sure it's only white and transparent alpha else it'll look like a white square block.